# how to return matplotlib axis from a function and assign it to matplotlib Figure Canvas?

Tags: python, pyqt6

I have a matplotlib Figure Canvas and a matplotlib axis returned by a function. Is it possible to assign this returned axis to matplotlib Figure Canvas?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qtagg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

def make_axis():
    f, ax = plt.subplots(111)
    ax.plot([range(10)], [range(10)])
    plt.close(f)
    return ax

   
fig = Figure()
canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
axes = canvas.figure.subplots()


ax = make_axis()
axes = ax   # is it possible to assign an axis like this?
canvas.draw()
```

Comment: What happens when you try it?